# Random error 80020009 accesing an Access 2000 database from a classic asp webpage

Tags: asp-classic

I am running a query from a classic asp webpage to a Microsoft Access 2000 database table to return a query of names and to perform a calculation. The database has been running for years, and all queries in the past have been succesful. All of a sudden the past few months, some of the names and calculations are displayed, the following error appears: error 80020009. On the bottom of the displayed query, a person's name is displayed, but the calculation field is not displayed; it is blank. The calculation feild is using a count option in classic asp, and is a text data type in Microsoft Access. As the error message never appeared until the last few months, this is very strange. I was able to find the records in Microsoft Access table (in my development environment) which was causing the errors for a specific month, but I don't want to have to delete the records in a production environment. If I run a sql query in Microsoft Access, all of the records in a given month in the table (where the issues apepars) are fine, and no errors appear. I have exported and imported the Access table, but the 8002009 error still appears.

Has anyone experienced an issue like this? Does it sound like a classic asp coding issue, or an issue with the Microsoft Access 2000 database table itself.

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: No such thing as a random error. Did you google ms access 80020009 , 27,900 hits...

Comment: You going to show any code or do you expect us to just guess?

Comment: Yes have googled the 8002009 error, and it coud be possible there are some null records. Is there a way I can verify this?

Comment: I will post my asp code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <div>
    <br />
    <h1 class="main">CO Report</h1>
    <hr class="main">
    <blockquote>        
      <form method="POST" action="os.asp" name="form2">
        <p>Month to Query:&nbsp;
            <select size="1" name="ddmonth">
         <%
            dim i
            for i = 1 to 12
              if i = month(date) then
            %>  <option selected value="<%=i%>"><%=monthname(i)%></option>
            <%  'select the current month
              else
            %>  <option value="<%=i%>"><%=monthname(i)%></option>
            <%
              end if
            next
          %></select> <select size="1" name="ddyear">
          <% 
            dim intyear
            for intyear = 2001 to year(date)
                response.write ("<option selected>" & intyear & "</option>")
            next
          %></select>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Query CS" name="btnQUERY"></p>            
    </form>
    <hr /><br />
    <%
      if request.form("btnQUERY") <> "" then
      'display the table based on the selected month and year

      'setup query
      strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=d:\store\stats\data\pros.mdb"
      Set cnn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      cnn.Open strConn

      'open the recordset
      Set rstData = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
      rstDATA.open "SELECT * FROM [tv] ORDER BY toc", cnn, adOpenKeyset        
    %>
      <table border="1" width="100%" id="AutoNumber2" height="18" cellspacing="1">
        <caption>CU-Out Results for <%=monthname(Request.form("ddmonth"))%>, <%=request.form("ddyear")%></caption>            
        <tr>
          <th>Officer's Name</th>
          <th>Minutes Achieved - CUW</th>
          <th>Net Minutes Worked (hours worked - exception)</th>
          <th>% of Productivity</th>
        </tr>
      <%  'set up date values
          dim year2, day2, month2 
          year2 = Trim(Request.form("ddyear"))
          month2 = Trim(Request.form("ddmonth"))
          'open up the cuot data for the month
          Set rstData1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 'cuot
          'open up the table to grab the names of those who entered data during that month selected
          rstDATA1.open "SELECT DISTINCT [name] FROM cuot WHERE month(date)= '" & month2 & "' and year(date) ='" & year2 & "' ORDER BY [name]", cnn, adOpenKeyset
          Set rstData3 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 'hours worked
          Set rstData4 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 'exception
        do until rstDATA1.eof = true
      %><tr>
          <td><%=rstDATA1("name")%>&nbsp;</td>
       <% 'do the math calculations for minute achieved
          Set rstData0 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 'cuot
          rstDATA0.open "SELECT count(toc) as COUNT1, toc FROM cuot WHERE [name] = '" & replace(rstDATA1("name"), "'", "''") & "' and month(date)= '" & month2 & "' and year(date) ='" & year2 & "' GROUP BY toc ORDER BY toc", cnn, adOpenKeyset
          rstDATA.movefirst 'tv table to get "minutes achieved"
          rstDATA0.movefirst 'cuot list
          CUachieved = 0    
          do until rstDATA0.eof = true   
              'loop through rstDATA.toc until match found for rstDATA0.toc
              do until trim(rstDATA("toc")) = trim(rstDATA0("toc"))
                  rstDATA.movenext
              loop
              if rstDATA("per_day") <> "0" then CUachieved = cDBL(CUachieved) + (cDBL(rstDATA0("COUNT1"))/cDBL(rstDATA("per_day"))*450) 
              rstDATA.movenext
              rstDATA0.movenext
          loop
          %><td><%=round(CUachieved)%>&nbsp;</td>
          <%   'open up the hoursworked table 
         rstDATA3.open "Select * FROM monthlyhr WHERE [name] = '" & replace(rstDATA1("name"), "'", "''") & "' and month(date) ='" & month2 & "' and year(date) = '" & year2 & "'", cnn, adOpenKeyset    
         'should only ever be one record, so only check if there are no records
          if rstDATA3.eof = true then 
              %><td>N/A</td>
            <% 'net minutes worked
              %><td>N/A</td>
            <% '% of productivity
          else
              'open up the exception table
              'get approved exception
              rstDATA4.open "Select [name], sum(approval) as SUM1 from [exception] where [name] = '" & replace(rstDATA1("name"), "'", "''") & "' and month(date) ='" & month2 & "' and year(date) = '" & year2 & "' GROUP BY [name]", cnn, adOpenKeyset     
              if rstDATA4.eof = true then
                  exception2 = 0
              else 
                  exception2 = rstDATA4("sum1")
              end if
              rstDATA4.close
              'do the math for actual (hours worked + overtime - leave -exception)
              hoursworked2 = (cDBL(rstDATA3("hours")) + cDBL(rstDATA3("ot")) - cDBL(rstDATA3("leave")) - cDBL(exception2))
              %><td><%=hoursworked2*60%>&nbsp;</td>
              <%
              'calculate percentage of csu+ops/minutes worked   
              percentTOTAL = ROUND(cDBL(CUachieved)/(cDBL(hoursworked2)*60)*100) 'percent
              %><td><%=percentTOTAL%>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <%
          end if
       rstDATA1.movenext
       rstDATA3.close
      loop  
          rstDATA.close     'close all databases
          set rstDATA = nothing
          rstDATA1.close
          set rstDATA1 = nothing
          set rstDATA3 = nothing    
          set rstDATA4 = nothing  
          cnn.close
          set cnn=nothing

      %>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <% 
      end if 'end query%>
    </blockquote>
    </div>
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div>
    <!-- End of div.blackborder -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the Microsoft Access error message. In my coding, there is a connection to a 2nd database which lists headings. A few months ago I created new headings, and because I wanted them to appear all the top of the row, I indented them by adding a space. Once I removed the sapce for all of the new headings, the error message for the past few months disappeared, and the reports displayed perfectly.

Thank you to everyone for your suggestions.